# How to remove Edittext from a layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am able to dynamically add edittext into layout on button click.
now i want user to also be able to remove the respective edittext.

I am able to delete edittext from arraylist, But i also want it to be gone from my layout/Screen.

how do i do it?
Is it possible?
any help would be appreciated.
Thanking you in advance.

Code Reference:

Adding Edittext to arraylist first:

```
ArrayList<EditText> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Button> listbtn = new ArrayList<>();
```

Step 2:

```
spinnerAdd_Field.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, final Object item)
            {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked " + item, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                {

                    editText = new EditText(Add_Account.this);
                    btnremove = new Button(Add_Account.this);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpb = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 120);
                    lpb.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                    lpb.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 32);
                    btnremove.setLayoutParams(lpb);
                    btnremove.setPadding(46, 0,0,0);
                    btnremove.setText( "Remove\n"+item.toString());
                    btnremove.setId(count);
                    btnremove.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    btnremove.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundrounded);
                    btnremove.setOnClickListener(btnclick);

                  
                    {
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 120);
                        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 32);
                        editText.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        editText.setPadding(46, 0,0,0);
                        editText.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A17A7979"));
                        editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_edittex);
                        editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7A7979"));
                        editText.setHint(item.toString());
                    }


                    if(btnremove.getParent() != null) {
                        ((ViewGroup)btnremove.getParent()).removeView(btnremove); // <- fix
                    }

                    myLayout.addView(editText);
                    myLayoutbtn.addView(btnremove);

                    // for each EditText add it to the ArrayList
                    for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        list.add(editText);
                    }

                    // for each Button also add it to the ArrayList
                    for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        listbtn.add(btnremove);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        });
```

Check this image for reference:

[image: Check This:]

Comment: You can set the visibility to INVISIBLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove View from layout you should use removeView() method. In your case:

```
mLayout.removeView(editText);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, was stuck on it for hours.
Dang, it was so simple!